# Can't install .sh file

Tags: wireless, command-line, bash, permissions

OK, I know there are over 100 questions on this forum just like this one, I know because I've read every one of them, with no luck. I have downloaded a `.bin` file, extracted the contents into a folder. Which gives me a `.sh` file to install. I have:

1. made sure it was executable both in dolphin, and the file properties itself
2. Tried

   ```
   sudo chmod 777 filename.sh
   sudo chmod +x filename.sh
   ```
3. tried to run it in terminal by typing in:

   ```
   sh ./filename.sh
   source ~./filename.sh
   /bin/bash/filename.sh
   source ./filename.sh
   sudo ./filename.sh
   !/bin/bash/filename.sh
   sudo bash/ filename.sh
   ```

   and some more, on another terminal window I've closed, so I don't remember what all it was.

This is a driver for my Belkin router, so I can utilize the USB ports on the router, which I need for my home network.

No  matter what I do, I either get an error of some type, or it just returns, but never installs. As you can see I've spent a lot of time on this, trying every possible way I could find, I even downloaded the `dh-make` software from the repository, which is supposed to make files executable, didn't work. So what am I doing wrong? Is there another way I can try, I really need to get this installed. Normally I won't download anything from the internet, if I can't get it in a repository, I do without. However I got this from Belkin, a major company so I feel I can trust it. Please Help.

EDIT: Ok, there was no output of any of the things I tried, I typed in the command, hit enter, and instantly had another prompt. That was it. The result of the "head -n1" command, was #!bin bash.

Here is the address where I downloaded the file

[Download Belkin F9K1103 Router Firmware 1.00.42 for Linux](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/FIRMWARE/Belkin/Belkin-F9K1103-Router-Firmware-10042-for-Linux.shtml)

btw. just wanted to say, I don't know what happened on my formatting, but the edits that were made was the way I originally put it in. I don't know why it jumbled into one paragraph like that. Thank you to whoever corrected it, it just bugs me it didn't keep the formatting I put in.

Comment: Good that you have provided with what you have tried, but would be better if you could also provide the output you got(whatever it may be) when you tried those commands(Eg. Output of `bash filename.sh`, etc.).

Comment: Could you point us to the file which you want to install?

Comment: Perhaps also include the output of `head -n1 filename.sh`.

Comment: I'm totally not sure how much this relates, but, look inside your system logs after each time you run the script, maybe you see errors or other useful messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You extracted a BIN file??

Please don't do that. =]

```
chmod 777 <name>.bin
./<name>.bin
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one the file you linked in the your URL is a .run file not a .sh file.

so if you try to run it using bash there's no guarantees that it'll work.

The only thing you didn't try in your list of attempts is to run it using

./filename, or in this case.

```
chmod a+x N750-GPL-1.00.42.run
./N750-GPL-1.00.42.run
```

Also, if you do get an error when you do ./filename.sh.  (I do see that you tried sudo ./filename.sh ) it would be helpful to see what the error might be.

Comment: How did you get a .run file? I re-down-loaded this morning just to make sure, and it downloaded as a .bin file. I double click the file, and it ask if I want to open in Ark, or 7Zip, it unpacks 7 folders, a read-me.txt, and the SetUpEnv.sh. If I can get a .run file, that would be great it would make things so much better.

Comment: I'll try to do this again now that I'm on normal internet once more.


1.  http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/FIRMWARE/Belkin/Belkin-F9K1103-Router-Firmware-10042-for-Linux.shtml 
2.  Click on the big Download Button
3.  Clicked on the "External Mirror" link
4.  Prompted to save file by the name listed above.

I'm re-downloading it now, and I'll comment on the results

Comment: Update:  So, then .run file is basically just an archive.  Once extracted you have the a readme file with instructions.

  1. copy or move mipsel-linux-uclibc to /opt
  2. $ source SetUpEnv.sh
  3. $ brh
  4. $ ./go.sh
./go.sh runs fine for me, though I get a compilation error.  Did you get this far?   Your initial question was about running .sh file.  At this point it's probably a missing lib or well actual card that I don't have to go with this drive or a combination of the two.

Comment: I give up, I'll return this and do something different.

Answer (score 0):

Just go ahead and lock this, I have done other things and don't need this anymore as I could not get it to work.